# Cucumber/Java - Missing "matching glue code"

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber

I've setup some automation in Eclipse using Java, Cucumber and Selenium.
I've defined my Feature file, Steps and been using a Page Object Model and all my tests are running and reporting successfully.
However, I'm getting a warning on every Step saying it "does not have matching glue code". I've tried modifying my path names and moving the files around, but that just seems to cause issues that prevent it running.

Using cucumber 6.2.2 jars and cucumber-expressions 10.2.1

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wdDA.png)

```html
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/functionalTests"},
        tags = "@register2",
        glue = {"stepDefinitions"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports.html"},
        monochrome = true
        )
```

Comment: To start try putting the runner class and the glue classes in the same package and removing `glue` from the options. By default the glue is the package of the runner class.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje thanks for the reply, I tried that and it still had the warning of missing glue code and then also my first test started failing during the run.

Comment: Try starting from scratch with the and see if you can make that work. If that works you gotta dig into your project and find the differences. https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

In your glue option can you write full package name.
For example:

```
com.testautomation.test.stepdefinitions
```